# Is dua allowed after khutba?

Tags: dua, jumuah, khutbah

I would like to know, whether it is allowed to make `dua` after the `Khutba` (is it called sermon?) given by any Iman (say in Friday prayer, Eid prayers).

I have heard different views from different people as to some say *dua* is not to be made after the khutba, and some say it is one of the moments when your *dua*  gets accepted. But, these views were never supported by any reference.

Can anyone elaborate on this point with proper reference to authentic sources?

Comment: can you mention a reference for " say dua is not to be made after the khutba"? there is no problem to make dua after khutba.

Comment: You are asking two things in one: *Is it called sermon?* and *Is dua allowed after Khutba?*. Please ask the second question separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is it permissible for Khateeb (Imam) to make du'aa after the Khutbah of Jum'a (Friday)?

Yes it is, and in fact it's authentic that the prophet did make duaa after the Khutbah. **However**, the point of confusion is that:

#### Is it permissible for Imam and people to raise their hands while making this du'aa?

- For the **Imam**, he shouldn't raise his hands, but rather raise only his forefinger, as the Prophet only raise his forefinger while making du'aa after Khutbah of Jum'aa.

  > Allah, disfigure these hands! I have seen Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) gesture no more than this with his hands, and he pointed with his forefinger.
  >
  > وَحَدَّثَنَا أَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ إِدْرِيسَ، عَنْ حُصَيْنٍ، عَنْ عُمَارَةَ، بْنِ رُؤَيْبَةَ قَالَ رَأَى بِشْرَ بْنَ مَرْوَانَ عَلَى الْمِنْبَرِ رَافِعًا يَدَيْهِ فَقَالَ قَبَّحَ اللَّهُ هَاتَيْنِ الْيَدَيْنِ لَقَدْ رَأَيْتُ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم مَا يَزِيدُ عَلَى أَنْ يَقُولَ بِيَدِهِ هَكَذَا . وَأَشَارَ بِإِصْبَعِهِ الْمُسَبِّحَةِ .
  >
  > [[Sahih Muslim]](https://sunnah.com/muslim:873c), with other versions available like [this](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/715).
- For **people**, who say Ameen after him, some scholars say that they shouldn't raise their hands as it's not recorded that people raised their hands while the Prophet made dua'a after the Khutbah of Jum'aa. While other scholars say that they can raise their hands, because of the many Hadiths about how good raising hands while making duaa is, like this one:

  > Narrated Salman al-Farsi:
  > The Prophet said: Your Lord is munificent and generous, and is ashamed to turn away empty the hands of His servant when he raises them to Him.
  >
  > حَدَّثَنَا مُؤَمَّلُ بْنُ الْفَضْلِ الْحَرَّانِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا عِيسَى، - يَعْنِي ابْنَ يُونُسَ - حَدَّثَنَا جَعْفَرٌ، - يَعْنِي ابْنَ مَيْمُونٍ صَاحِبَ الأَنْمَاطِ - حَدَّثَنِي أَبُو عُثْمَانَ، عَنْ سَلْمَانَ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم  " إِنَّ رَبَّكُمْ تَبَارَكَ وَتَعَالَى حَيِيٌّ كَرِيمٌ يَسْتَحْيِي مِنْ عَبْدِهِ إِذَا رَفَعَ يَدَيْهِ إِلَيْهِ أَنْ يَرُدَّهُمَا صِفْرًا " .
  >
  > [[Sunan Abu-Dawud]](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/8/73).

  And since there's nothing mentioning that people should raise hands in the Dua'a after the Khutbah of Jum'aa, then they can.

And Allah knows best.